# How can i make this wave effect on both bottom and top

Tags: css

I would like the bottom wave effect on top too! Can anyone show me how it's done.

The effect should look the same on the top of where it is placed on the top as well as the bottom.

I am actually trying to do is break a image top and bottom with waves, so that partial top and bottom of image disappears in waves.

[image: Open Image]

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

//variables
$background: #FFF;

body {
  background-color: $background;
  color: #ffF;
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wave{
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, sandybrown, chocolate);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.wave::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, white 13px);
}
.wave::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, white 12px, transparent 13px);
}
.content {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>CSS Rounded Borders</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wave">I'm wavy</div>
  
  <div class="content">
    With two special pseudo elements (before and after) and the power of repeating css3 radial gradients this ruffle like waves are done much easier than before without an image file.
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: I am sorry its my first time here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one part using the pseudo elements and the other using multiple background:

```css
.wave{
  text-align: center;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, white 12px, transparent 13px) left 0 bottom -5px/40px 20px repeat-x,
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, white 13px) left 0 bottom -10px/20px 20px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, sandybrown, chocolate);
  padding:40px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.wave::before,
.wave::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  transform:scaleY(-1);
}
.wave::before{
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, white 13px);
}
.wave::after{
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, white 12px, transparent 13px);
}
```

```html
  <div class="wave">I'm wavy</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the question. could you please check

Comment: @DileepP in my code I am using multiple background, so if you want to use an image change only this `linear-gradient(to bottom, sandybrown, chocolate)` with the image .. don't change all the background or you will break the bottom part